# How to check if JSON contains field and have value Sequelize MySQL (MariaDB)

Tags: mysql, json, node.js, mariadb, sequelize.js

I am using Node.js Sequelize with MySQL (MariaDB) database.

How to check if JSON field contains specified field and this field have value?

Example of my column `data`:

```
{
 "a": true,
 "b": true,
}
```

I need to select only rows when `b` is defined AND his value is `true`

Answer (score 1):

This should be very old now, but I believe this answer should certainly help someone looking for this using either MariaDB or MySql which doesn't have the **JSONB** datattype... I had Similar challenge although a little different, after a couple of search I stumbled upon the [Sequelize GitHub Issue - Op.contains fails on MySQL JSON arrays #8853](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/8853) and with the help of the [Sequelize Official Documentation](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-basics/#operators) I was able to come up with a solution which worked as expected, I had to make sure I had a working raw sql version before trying to translate it to Sequelize, below should be the sql version of your expected solution:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `table_name` where JSON_CONTAINS(data, '[{"b": true}]');
```

And here is the Sequelize solution;

```js
const allData = await ModelName.findAll({
    where: {
        [Op.or]: [sequelize.fn('JSON_CONTAINS', sequelize.col('data'), `[{"b": true}]`)]
          }
});
```

You can use `.then()` if you're not within an `async` function. Do reach back if you have any further concern or you're having challenge adapting this solution to your specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Model.findAll({
 where: sequelize.where(sequelize.literal('data->>\'$.b\''), true)
})
```